# What determines the load address for an ios app?

Tags: ios, crash-dumps, symbolicatecrash

Up until very recently (around november 4th, 2012) the crash dumps from our ios app always had a load address of 0x1000. We never used the -l option in atos and we still got good results so I assume it defaults to 0x1000. Over the last week we were having difficulties tracing crashes and it turned out the load addresses have been different in every crash log since november 4th.

Does anyone know what determines the load address?

Is it something that Apple has done recently or possibly something that our app has done to cause this?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the base address from a crash report by looking at the 'Binary Images' section at the bottom of the report. The first entry is your binary image with a range of addresses, take the first one and pass it to `atos` as load address.

An example of crash report:

```
[...]
Binary Images:
0x1000 - 0xfcfff +YOUR_BINARY_NAME armv7  <9b381f1828fa3a888d4fbc4175f9a16d> /var/mobile/Applications/FD624263-D877-4F07-BC1F-5E6703A78D07/YOUR_APP.app/YOUR_BINARY_NAME
0x7ba000 - 0x7befff  AccessibilitySettingsLoader armv7   /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader
[...]
```

`0x1000` is the loading address you are looking for.